# Can Access Query Builder use a dynamic form name as criteria for drop-down list?

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple query as a Row Source for a combo box. It returns a list of Departments associated to a Customer.  The returned values are used to populate a drop-down list on a form (Workorders by Customer) for the end-user to select from.

I now need to add a new form that will have the same type of department-selection functionality.

The code in Query Builder has a hard-coded reference to the original form in the criteria. (Workorders by Customer)

I would like to now re-use this query for the new form's drop-down list.

Is there a way to turn the form-name criteria into something dynamic so it gets the name of the calling form instead of hard-coding the calling form's name?  Like something similar to VBA's usage of "Me."?

I've tried Me.[CustID] in the Query Builder criteria but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

```
SELECT tblDepartments.ID, tblDepartments.CustID, tblDepartments.DeptName
FROM tblDepartments
WHERE (((tblDepartments.CustID)=[Forms]![Workorders by Customer]![CustID]))
ORDER BY tblDepartments.DeptName;
```

Comment: I don't think so. Probably require two query objects or maybe instead of query object, put SQL statement in form RecordSource. I prefer to avoid dynamic parameterized queries as much as possible and instead use VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: Good idea about coding it in the Record Source.  This query is simple enough that having it there is not an issue.  In this case, it's for generating a list of values for a drop-down box and the SQL is very simple so this is a good solution.  Thanks again!